# How CPU-Z app gives max battery capacity ( in mAh) in Android?

Tags: java, android, batterymanager

This code gives me 2000 on every single device and all the previous questions of this problem on SO gives irrelevant answers.

Please somebody help

```
public void getBatteryCapacity() {
    Object mPowerProfile_ = null;

    final String POWER_PROFILE_CLASS = "com.android.internal.os.PowerProfile";

    try {
        mPowerProfile_ = Class.forName(POWER_PROFILE_CLASS)
                .getConstructor(Context.class).newInstance(getContext());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        double batteryCapacity = (Double) Class
                .forName(POWER_PROFILE_CLASS)
                .getMethod("getAveragePower", java.lang.String.class)
                .invoke(mPowerProfile_, "battery.capacity");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), batteryCapacity + " mah",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("Capacity",batteryCapacity+" mAh");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But I want max capacity like CPU-Z app gives:

[image]

Comment: replace `getContext()` with `this` keyword.

Comment: @Amy after replacing getContext()  the method is not even running :(

Comment: What is you class's super class?

Comment: it's a fragment in MainActivity

Comment: use `getActivity()` instead.

Comment: @Amy again 2000

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling getMaxPower or something, instead of getAveragePower?

Comment: please refer to the documentation http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/4.4_r1-robolectric-1/com/android/internal/os/PowerProfile.java#PowerProfile.getBatteryCapacity%28%29

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation attached along with the source code of the [PowerProfile](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/4.4_r1-robolectric-1/com/android/internal/os/PowerProfile.java#PowerProfile.getBatteryCapacity%28%29) class, the method `getAveragePower()`
returns:

> the average current in milliAmps.

Instead you have to use `getBatteryCapacity()` which returns

> the battery capacity in mAh

And hence, you have to change the method invocation as `getBatteryCapacity()` takes no arguments unlike `getAveragePower()` which takes two arguments, so the code will be like:

```
public void getBatteryCapacity() {
    Object mPowerProfile_ = null;

    final String POWER_PROFILE_CLASS = "com.android.internal.os.PowerProfile";

    try {
        mPowerProfile_ = Class.forName(POWER_PROFILE_CLASS)
                .getConstructor(Context.class).newInstance(this);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    try {
        double batteryCapacity = (Double) Class
                .forName(POWER_PROFILE_CLASS)
                .getMethod("getBatteryCapacity")
                .invoke(mPowerProfile_);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, batteryCapacity + " mah",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Comment: it too gives 2000 because getBatteryCapcity returns getAveragePower

Comment: the app ?!! I think they are using another way, even there is another way we don't know, or they are using a way related to API 20 and above only.

Comment: This App https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cpuid.cpu_z&hl=en  gives correct value

Comment: or may be they checking the device model and compare it to a prestored db.

Comment: How could they?  App last updated in feb 2016 and so many devices launch every day